# sed swallows braces / curly brackets

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I've got a LaTeX file containing

```tex
\newcommand{\revision}{value}
```

And during CI I want to do the following:

```bsh
REV=${CI_COMMIT_TAG:-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
sed -i 's/{\\revision}{\(\w*\)}/\1'"$REV"'/' variables.tex
```

expecting something along the lines of `\newcommand{\revision}{577f813d}`

Unfortunately this happens:

```bsh
> REV=test sed 's/{\\revision}{\(\w*\)}/\1'"$REV"'/' variables.tex
\newcommandvaluetest
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: can u echo `$REV` and share the result

Comment: That part works $ echo $REV
758d59ea

Comment: Looks like it does what is programmed: eliminate the `{`s and `}`s, and the `\revision` string, then adds the `test` string.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed -e "s/\({\\\revision}\){\w*}/\1{$REV}/" variables.tex

\newcommand{\revision}{577f813d}
```

- sed required two black slashes to escape backslash.
- We should back-reference the  `{\\\revision}` instead of `{\w*}`
- finally required a curl brace around `REV` as per our expected output

Comment: This is it, I just placed the capture group in the wrong place. Without extended regex: `sed 's/\({\\revision}{\)[^}]*/\1'"$REV"'/'`